# Как импортировать отдельные тесты unittest без выполнения остального кода донорского модуля?

Tags: юнит-тесты, python-unittest

Имеются два файла:

- основной, из которого будет запускаться группа тестов, общих для разных вариантов тестирования,
- и один из дополнительных, где имеются тесты для одного из интерфейсов
  сайта.

Тесты выполняются успешно. Но перед выполнением тестов модуля *common_base.py* выполняется весь модуль *test_set1*.

**Вопрос** - как добавить в процесс выполнения *common_base.py* тесты из модуля *test_set1* так, чтобы не
выполнялись остальные тесты модуля *test_set1*? Или чтобы они не выполнялись хотя бы перед тем как эти тесты будут запрошены в ходе выполнения тестов основного модуля *common_base.py*.

Добавление `if __name__ == '__main__':` в код любого из модулей приводит к пропуску всех следующих за выражением тестов.

Основной файл *common_base.py* выглядит примерно так:

```
import unittest
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from test_set1 import MyTestCase


login = ''
password = ''

url = 'common_base_url'

s = Service('chromedriver/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

def auth(a, b):
    if 'user_nickname' in driver.page_source:
        try:
            user_nickname_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "user_nickname")
            user_pass_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "user_password")
            submit_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type = submit]")
            user_nickname_input.send_keys(login)
            user_pass_input.send_keys(password)
            submit_input.click()
            time.sleep(3)
        except WebDriverException:
            print('не удалось найти на странице какой-либо из ожидаемых элементов: user_nickname, user_password, input[type = submit]')
    else: print("аутентификация не потребовалась")

def method2():
    print('common_base.method2')
def method3():
    print('common_base.method3')

class Common(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_1_open_sitemap(self):
        driver.get(url)
        driver.maximize_window()
        auth(login, password)
        time.sleep(3)

        self.assertTrue(' \\ expected text' in driver.page_source)

        time.sleep(3)

    def test_2_do_something(self):
        # код теста 2

    # ЗДЕСЬ НЕОБХОДИМО ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ ТЕСТЫ ОДНОГО ИЛИ БОЛЬШЕ ВСПОМОГАТЕЛЬНЫХ ФАЙЛОВ: test_set1.py test_set2.py
        MyTestCase.test_1(self)

    def test_5_do_something(self):
        # код теста 5

    def test_6_back_to_url(self):
        backbutton = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-original-title="Наверх"]')
        self.assertTrue(str(len(backbutton))=='1')
        backbutton[0].click()
    
driver.quit()
```

Примерный код *test_set1.py*:

```
import unittest
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
 
s = Service('chromedriver/chromedriver')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

driver.maximize_window()

url = 'test_set1_url'    
operator_login = ''
operator_phone = ''

def operator_auth(a, b):
    'Аутентификация оператора'
    # если поле ввода логина имеется, то вводим логин и номер телефона, и отправляем
    if 'login' in driver.page_source:
        try:
            user_login = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "login")
            user_phone_number = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "instrument")
            submit_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "login-button")
            user_login.send_keys(operator_login)
            user_phone_number.send_keys(operator_phone)
            submit_button.click()
            time.sleep(3)
            print("аутентификация оператора проведена")
        except WebDriverException:
            print(
                'не удалось найти на странице какой-либо из ожидаемых элементов: user_login, user_phone_number, submit_button')
    else:
        print("поле login не найдено")

    
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    operator_auth(operator_login, operator_phone)

    def test_1(self):
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)
        self.assertTrue(" \\ expected text" in driver.page_source)

    def test_2(self):
        #код теста 2

    def test_3(self):
        #код теста 3

    
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Все работает не так, как вы себе представляете. Допустим код верхнего уровня из `test_set1.py` не будет выполнятся. Откуда тогда возмется значение в `driver` при вызове функции `test_1`? Оно ведь сейчас создается кодом верхнего уровня.

Comment: @Roman-Stop, в базовом модуле `common_base.py` есть тот же "код верхнего уровня", если вы подразумеваете код, предшествующий классу. и даже если мой расчет верен, это не исключает, что все работает не так как я себе представляю. если знаете как должно работать - поясните, пожалуйста. 

после вашего замечания я уточнил слегка вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Уберите весь код с верхнего уровня:

```
# common_base.py

# тут не должно быть создания драйвера как было раньше
# это все перемещено в setUpClass теста

class Common(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        s = Service('chromedriver/chromedriver')
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
        cls.set1 = MyTestCase(cls.driver)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
       cls.driver.quit()

    def auth(self, a, b):
        if 'user_nickname' in self.driver.page_source:
            try:
                user_nickname_input = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "user_nickname")
                ... тут как и было только вместо driver используем self.driver
            except WebDriverException:
                 # вместо print нужно бросать AssertError с помощью метода self.fail
                 # self.fail('не удалось найти на странице какой-либо из ожидаемых элементов: user_nickname, user_password, input[type = submit]')
                 # тогда тест не будет продолжать выполнение в случае ошибки
                 print('не удалось найти на странице какой-либо из ожидаемых элементов: user_nickname, user_password, input[type = submit]')
        else: print("аутентификация не потребовалась")

    def method2(self):
        print('common_base.method2')

    def method3(self):
        print('common_base.method3')

    def test_1_open_sitemap(self):
        self.driver.get(url)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.auth(login, password)
        time.sleep(3)

        self.assertTrue(' \\ expected text' in self.driver.page_source)

        time.sleep(3)

    def test_2_do_something(self):
        # код теста 2

    def test_3_do_something(self):
        # код теста 3    

    def test_4_test_1(self):
        self.set1.test_1()

    def test_4_test_2(self):
        self.set1.test_2()

    def test_5_do_something(self):
        # код теста 5

    def test_6_back_to_url(self):
        backbutton = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-original-title="Наверх"]')
        ...

# driver.quit() тоже переехал в tearDownClass чтобы он выполнялся не во время импорта
# а после выполнения теста
```

Так как `MyTestCase` вызывается из `Common`, то его вообще не нужно наследовать от `unittest.TestCase`, а `driver` передавать при создании:

```
# test_set1.py

class MyTestCase:

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def test_1(self):
        self.driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)
        self.assertTrue(" \\ expected text" in driver.page_source)

    def test_2(self):
        #код теста 2

    def test_3(self):
        #код теста 3
```

Comment: импорты, видимо, должны остаться в обоих файлах? они там активны (используются). и что передается в качестве аргумента cls: def setUpClass(cls) ?

Comment: Объект класса, только вам не нужно об этом беспокоится. Этот метод вызывает unittest.

Comment: в `@classmethod def setUpClass(cls)` `self` оказывается неопределенным. что выглядит логичным - вместо него передается `cls`. правильно ли вторым аргументом передать `self=None`?

аналогично, не определен (Unresolved reference) `driver` в `def tearDownClass(cls): cls.driver.quit()` и в последующих методах. как его подтянуть?

Comment: это была опечатка. должно быть cls

Comment: если не против, я сразу буду отписывать затруднения, пока горячо. а то, к тому времени когда станет понятно могу ли разобраться сам, вам, возможно, и не захочется возвращаться к вопросу. 1) На `cls.driver` в выражении `cls.set1 = MyTestCase(cls.driver)` PyCharm сообщает *"Expected type 'str', got 'WebDriver' instead. Unresolved attribute reference 'driver' for class 'Common'"*. 2) ну и в последующих методах driver по-прежнему не определен

Comment: 3) в вашем примере остались неопределены некоторые переменные *test_set1.py*. поэтому я дополнил текст конкретным методом где они используются, чтобы была понятна их необходимость. т.к. я не знаком с предложенной  вами конструкцией, то пример их определения здорово помог бы

Comment: Ответ я написал в таком же стиле (с такими же подробностями и гранулярностью) как и вопрос. Это демонстрация подхода, а не готовый код. Если вы приведете минимальный воспроизводимый пример сфокусированный на одной проблеме (так чтоб можно было скопировать и запустить), то и ответ будут самозапускаемым и рабочим. Почему у вас не работает - сказать трудно. Как минимум я не знаю, как именно вы воспользовались кодом, что я привел. Нужно видеть конкретный код с конкретными ошибками. С отладкой через комментарии я не помогу. Задавайте конкретные (новые) вопросы по непонятным моментам в ответе.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139066/discussion-between-roman-stop-ru-aggression-in-ua-and-simply-one).

Comment: логично. ок, тогда еще попробую сделать что смогу и потом уже к вам. спасибо!

Comment: т.к. ваш код у меня не работает - возможно, в силу ошибок вне вашего решения - задал отдельный вопрос на универсальном примере https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460526

Comment: вы писали " Если вы приведете минимальный воспроизводимый пример сфокусированный на одной проблеме (так чтоб можно было скопировать и запустить), то и ответ будут самозапускаемым и рабочим." - что-то мешает дать ответ в обозначенном стиле на вопрос по ссылке выше?