# Как совместно использовать тесты Selenium-Python-Unittest, разбитые группами по модулям

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, python-unittest

**Проблема**: когда тестов много, помещать их все в один тест-кейс невыгодно, если приходится комбинировать и редактировать тесты группами и поодиночке.
Поэтому все дополнительные тесты хочу разнести группами по разным модулям. Далее эти тесты будут добавляться между стартовыми и заключительными обязательными тестами.

**Вопрос**: как технически (кодом) связать тесты из дополнительных модулей с основным?

Для примера, сейчас все тесты расположены линейно в одном файле `ya.py`.
Тесты `test_00_01_open_site` и `test_00_14_searching` являются базовыми, обязательными. Остальные, которые между ними, нужно в результате подтягивать из других файлов.

*Прошу дать примеры кода, который обеспечил бы такую связку.*

```
#ya.py 

import unittest
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


# Переменные окружения
login = 'login'
password = 'password'

# URL-s
url_ya = 'https://ya.ru'
url_passport = 'https://passport.yandex.ru'
url_welcome = 'auth/welcome'

# ChromeDriver
s = Service('../chromedriver/chromedriver')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

time_sleep = 1
i_wait = 5


def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_00_01_open_site(self):
        """открытие сайта"""

        driver.get(url_ya)
        driver.maximize_window()
        input_text = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'text')
        placeholder = input_text.get_attribute('placeholder')

        self.assertEqual(placeholder, 'найдётся всё')

    def test_00_10_enter(self):
        """переход на страницу авторизации"""

        a_enter = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Войти')
        a_enter.click()

        page_title = driver.title

        self.assertEqual(page_title, 'Авторизация')

    def test_00_11_log_in(self):
        """выбор способа авторизации через эл.почту"""

        button_phone = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@data-type = "phone"]')
        button_phone.click()

        if check_exists_by_xpath('//input[@id = "passp-field-login"]'):
            return True
        else:
            button_login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@data-type = "login"]')
            button_login.click()

        input_login = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'passp-field-login')
        placeholder = input_login.get_attribute('placeholder')

        self.assertTrue(placeholder == "Логин или email")

    def test_00_12_log_in(self):
        """ввод логина"""

        input_login = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'passp-field-login')
        placeholder = input_login.get_attribute('placeholder')
        print(placeholder)

        input_login.send_keys(login)
        button_signin = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'passp:sign-in')
        button_signin.click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(i_wait)
        input_passwd = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Введите пароль']")
        placeholder = input_passwd.get_attribute('placeholder')
        print(placeholder)
        self.assertTrue('Введите пароль' in driver.page_source)

    def test_00_13_passwd_in(self):
        """ввод пароля"""

        input_passwd = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'passp-field-passwd')
        input_passwd.send_keys(password)
        button_signin = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'passp:sign-in')
        button_signin.click()
        time.sleep(time_sleep)

        self.assertTrue('Неверный пароль' in driver.page_source)

    def test_00_14_searching(self):
        """отправка поискового запроса"""

        driver.get(url_ya)
        input_text = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'text')
        input_text.send_keys('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460526/')
        button_submit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@type = "submit"]')
        button_submit.click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(i_wait)

        self.assertTrue('Как совместно использовать тесты...' in driver.page_source)

        driver.quit()
```

Comment: По сравнению с предыдущим [вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1446459/218971) ничего принципиально не изменилось. Тут нет минимального и воспроизводимого примера (в коде пароли, относительные пути - скопировать и запустить не получится). Ответ на этот вопрос будет таким же как и там. Нужно сократить ненужное, убрать все эти логины, у вас основное я так понимаю - запуск селениум и использование одного driver-а на все тесты. Для этого не нужно делать логин (который мешает задать вопрос ), достаточно запустить браузер.

Comment: Ну и опять же, если с тем ответом не получилось запустить - значит неправильно поняли ответ и что-то делаете не так, сам подход - рабочий. Вычленяйте проблемы в отдельные конкретные вопросы.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA ваш ответ во многом имеет слабое отношение к моему вопросу, тем не менее необходимость авторизации убрал. остальные тесты необходимы для иллюстрации рабочей ситуации. если они вам мешают, можете код сократить